# Visual Studio: which source file includes a particular library (with "pragma comment")?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker

**EDIT**:solved with James McNellis' suggestion, which led me to the offending library. It was one I hadn't checked with dumpbin.

I'm building a Visual Studio 2013 project that links against static libraries using "#pragma comment" instead of listing the libraries in the project properties. After replacing the libraries with new versions, I'm getting a link error because it's still trying to find some of the old libraries, e.g. it can't find "library_v9.lib" when it should be linking "library_v12.lib" instead. How can I find where the old libraries are being requested? Here's what I've tried:

- Deleting all the objects, etc. and rebuilding from scratch.
- Searching for "#pragma comment" doesn't work because it's built up into several layers of macros, and the version number is obtained from _MSC_VER so the "9" and "12" never actually appear anywhere in the source.
- Running dumpbin /DIRECTIVES on all the libraries that get linked together into the executable. They all refer to the correct "12" library versions.

Comment: Link with `/verbose` and search the output for "library_v9.lib".

Comment: @TScherer You should probably add an answer to this question instead of the edit solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker has a `/verbose` switch that will cause it to print out a detailed log of what libraries it is opening, what symbols it is searching for, and why it is searching for those symbols.

Typically, the most straightforward way to debug this sort of issue is to add `/verbose` to the linker options, open the build log in a text editor, and search for the library name or symbol in which you're interested.  In this case, search for "library_v9.lib".  The linker will tell you what caused it to open that library.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Properties->Linker->Input section?

Comment: Yes, it wasn't there. It was another library that I hadn't checked with dumpbin, and linking with "/verbose" led me to it.